# Wubi Migration: Grub does not boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, migration

I migrated from a wubi install on a SSD (`dev/sda`), with the virtual disk on a separate drive (`/dev/sdb`), to a brand new partition on the separate drive

I recall during me running the `wubi-move` script, it stated that the bootloader and grub2 were being installed to `dev/sdb`. I migrated root and the swap to `dev/sdb4` and `dev/sdb5` respectively.

But when the computer boots, it continues to show the Windows Boot Manager, not the new Grub as I expect, and I am not sure how to resolve my issue. I can see that the migration was successful, so I am thinking there are probably many possible solutions. Can I just reinstall grub2 or something of that nature?

If possible, I would rather have grub boot first, and be able to remove the Wubi install from within windows to the original mounting point which was a 30 gig spot on `dev/sdb1`.

Comment: may I know why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having an issue e.g. Windows still boots first, not Ubuntu, then it is likely that you are still booting from your SSD drive (`/dev/sda`), not the drive with the migrated install on it (`/dev/sdb`).

Since you migrated to a different drive from the one you currently boot on, it is normal that Windows continues to boot. The [Wubi migration script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) is intentionally limited as to where it can install Grub - for safety purposes (and to keep things simple). If you need to change the drive boot order or boot from a different disk, this has to be done separately.

For example, if you don't want the drive boot order, and instead you want Grub in `/dev/sda` you can boot the migrated install (it's always available on the bottom of the Wubi Grub menu after migrating) and then install Grub to `/dev/sda`:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```